# How to set a marker/counter/label to an arbitrary piece of text?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Is it possible to attach a marker to just a place in text, not to section, sub-section, etc.?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\begin{document}
Alex (see~\ref{alex}) is a boy, 
Jessica (see~\ref{jessica}) is a girl.
[...]
\label{alex}\ref{alex}: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
\label{jessica}\ref{jessica}: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
\end{document}
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Alex (see 1) is a boy, 
Jessica (see 2) is a girl.
[...]
1: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
2: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
```

Makes sense?

Comment: The specific example could be done with an enumerated list, is there a reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: @Andrew This is just an example. Correct solution is proposed by Will Robertson below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can only `\ref`-er to a `\label` that has been attached to a counter using `\refstepcounter`. For example:

```
\newcounter{foo}
...
Alex (see~\ref{alex}) is a boy, 
Jessica (see~\ref{jessica}) is a girl.
[...]
\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo\label{alex}: Alex Johnson: 4 y.o.
\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo\label{jessica}: Jessica D.: 5 y.o.
```

Internally, this is the way that all labelling and referencing is done with sections, figures, and so on.

Answer (score 11):

For who ever might be interested, adapted from Will Robertson's solution:

Problem: You wish to have an enumeration (e.g. an enumeration of 'hypotheses' in a research proposal) throughout the text, and reference that enumeration in the text.

Solution: Define

```
\newcounter{hypothesiscounter}
\newcommand*{\hyplabel}[1]{H\refstepcounter{hypothesiscounter}\thehypothesiscounter\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\hypref}[1]{H\ref{#1}}
```

and use as:

```
This shall be hypothesis \hyplabel{HYP:CRAZY_HYPOTH}. I shall explain hypothesis \hypref{HYP:CRAZY_HYPOTH} below.
```